# Maximum list length of the BigQuery ArrayQueryParameter values parameter

Tags: python, google-bigquery, parameters, pybigquery

I am trying to query BigQuery through the Python API Client Library using query parameters, specifically an `ArrayQueryParameter`.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.cbsa`
    WHERE
        name IN UNNEST(@metros)
"""

# Problematic list length
LIST_LENGTH = 300000

# Example values list
values = ["Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA" for i in range(LIST_LENGTH)]

# Generate BigQuery job config
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    priority=bigquery.QueryPriority.BATCH,
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("metros", array_type="STRING", values=values),
    ]
)

# Generate BigQuery query job
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    job_config=job_config,
)

# Obtain results
results = query_job.result()
for row in results:
    print(row)
```

When the list length in the `ArrayQueryParameter` "values" parameter is 300000 or longer (approximately), **the query does not finish** and if I inspect the BigQuery logs I am getting the following error log:
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigquery.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bigquery/v2/projects/{...}/jobs?prettyPrint=false (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)'))) 2.05274303188268` 
But with the length of the list being 200000 or lower, there is no problem and the query results are returned.

From this log I interpret that I am exceeding the maximum list length of this "values" parameter, but don't find this to be included in BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.query.ArrayQueryParameter)...

Which is the maximum list length of the BigQuery `ArrayQueryParameter` "values" parameter? Is there any workaround to be able to perform a query with a 300000 or longer list length?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs states that

> The request size can be up to 10 MB, including additional properties like query parameters.

So I guess this might be the limit you are hitting.